# A travesty of upvoting

Tags: discussion, voting

See here: [How can I prove the last digit of $(2^{121985292}-1)$ is $5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1067059/how-can-i-prove-the-last-digit-of-2121985292-1-is-5/1067077#1067077)

The most upvoted solution, which has 13 upvotes, is nice, short, and intuitive, but not rigorous. The best rigorous solution has 3 upvotes while mine, which is more complete has 1.

Not really whining, but something seems wrong with the upvote system.

EDIT: He said:
2^1 ends in 2
2^2 ends in 4
2^3 ends in 8
2^4 ends in 6
2^5 ends in 2
2^4k ends in 6.

Why does 2^4k end in 6? It is not explained at all.

Comment: Welcome to SE! This is how it works. :-)

Comment: I don't think Fermat's Little Theorem is required to tell that $2^4$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $5$, or that $6 \times 6 = 36$ which also ends in $6$. There is rigor, and then there is unneeded rigor...

Comment: His answer was more or less a framework for an inductive proof so it's not that bad, in all honesty. The number of upvotes an answer receives is not a reflection of completeness or the beauty of an answer. I've had plenty of very complete and beautiful answers which didn't receive much attention whereas simple answers received a lot of attention. It sucks when an answer you worked hard on doesn't get a lot of attention but after a while, you let go of such notions. The answers are for the OP to learn from, not for you to gain fame from.

Comment: I didn't vote on that question, but if I had I would have voted for that answer. That answer computed until there was a repeat. This is the basis for a simple yet completely rigorous way to do it. These sorts of problems can be explained to grade school kids. (But yes, in general, voting can be arbitrary; that is its nature.)

Comment: The upvote button says "This answer is useful" not "This answer is rigorous".

Comment: This is off-topic but what about [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1063223/old-oxford-scholarship-question-aabb-ge-abba/1063250#1063250) ?

Comment: I like the answer. It is crystal clear, easily understood by almost anyone, and a straightforward induction argument makes it perfectly rigorous, as noted above.

Comment: If you want to discuss voting on this specific question, you should tag this as ([tag:sspecific-question]) (see the [tag-info](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/specific-question/info)). If you want to discuss general issue and this particular question only serves as an example, you should probably explain that in the post.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Welcome to Math.SE!  The StackExchange platform is (arguably) the best question and answer service online, but it does have issues; one of the most noticeable is that people do not always vote the way we think they should.

The best response you can have is to: 1) grow a thick skin, 2) answer questions for reasons other than reputation points, and 3) do your part by voting early and often.

An aside: with a username that contains the term "troll," you may find that people aren't too sympathetic when you complain. `:)`